# How to get the css for tooltip which appears on hover?

Tags: html, css, chrome-dev-editor

I am trying to get css used for hover tooltip by using inspect element in google chrome developer tool.Tooltip appears when I hover on edit pencil Icon. as soon as I move the mouse to inspect the tooltip it disappears. so I am unable to inspect that tooltip. 
[image]

`<span>
   <span class="fa fa-pencil fa-1x" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"></span>
</span>`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a custom Javascript or CSS tooltip plugin. It's a default tooltip by the OS system or the browser, using `title` attribute to display it, so you can't get or set it style.

By the way, you can use @Anie solution to use your own tooltip. Now you can easily set a custom style for your tooltip.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about @Anie solution. example or any useful link

Answer (score 0):

[This is exactly what you want to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogmid.png)

instead you want to create please copy this code.

```
<style>
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the 
  hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;

/* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
   visibility: visible;
}
</style>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Please see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use the console instead of element inspector.

In the console, write:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-pencil fa-1x");
```

The console will show you all elements with this class, and when you click the result, the element will focus so you can see it's style.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An element's position ('relative' here) provides positioning context for generated content. And an element has its own title-attribute which provides text of a styled and positioned pseudo element. Note the tabindex which allows focus for the element (hover is not the only way to interact with content) and the disabling of interaction with the pseudo/generated element. Adjust as desired.

```
<style>
.container{position:relative;}
[data-toggle="tooltip"]:active:before,
[data-toggle="tooltip"]:hover:before,
[data-toggle="tooltip"]:focus:before
{content:attr(title);border:1px solid black;background:#eee;color:black;position:absolute;top:-100%;padding:0.1em 0.3em;font-size:smaller;z-index:11;pointer-events:none;white-space:nowrap;}
</style>
<span class=container>...<span tabindex="0" class="fa fa-pencil fa-1x" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip">tooltip</span>...</span>
```